# Inserting element to container: copy constructor messes up pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, copy-constructor

My problem is that the *default copy constr. messes up my pointers.*

**Simplified version:**

- I have a  `A` class with the *default* copy constr.
- `A` has 2 member objects: `B` and `C`.
- `B` has a pointer to `C`.

**Situation:**

- I store `A` in a `std::vector`: `vector.emplace_back(A(...));`
- emplace_back does this:

  - **Creating** A (setting up **B's pointer to C**, etc)
  - **Copying** A into the vector. (**default** copy ctr: copies by **value**)
  - **Destroying** the "origin" A.

.
 **Result:**

- The storage has an `A` which has a `B` which has a pointer to the **old** A's C. Which doesn't exist anymore.

**Simple solution would be:**

- In `A` there would be pointers to `B` and `C`

But this is not so good because why should A have pointers, when it owns its B and C and B and C shares lifetime with A.

**Question:**

- Isn't there a better way than having pointers in A?
- Or isn't there a simplier way than messing with copy constructor implementations?
- I thought that emplace constructs "in-place", so why does it need a copy ctr?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Maybe you'd provide relevant sample code to see what's actually going on... Based on your description it seems that `C` should have a constructor taking the address of the proper `B` object and `A` should have suitable copy constructor/copy assignment to properly set the pointers on the contained `C` object.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was a hint to construct the object *in-place* but does not address the main issue of messing up the pointers. You need to post some sample code or an MCVE to get a complete solution.

Comment: An emplace can trigger a reallocation, which copies or moves the elements around

Comment: Btw.: This is the wrong way to use emplace - basically you are calling push_back. You should just oass the arguments needed for the construction of A to emplace_back, which can then construct A in place, without the need for a temporary.

Comment: Some example code with desired output vs actual output (even if its a compiler error thrown) would help out a lot in answering your question. A lot of users just like looking at code, not reading paragraphs

Comment: There are two ways with emplace, `vec.emplace(obj(1,2));` and `vec.emplace(1,2);`. One uses a temporary here.

Comment: Now I use the second way, and it is construated in place. But when the container grows, it moves the elements to the new container, so I need a move constructor. If my object is complex (A contains B and C, B contains D and E, D contains F, etc) (and B has a reference to C which is set in A's constructor. Lower elements can't access their owners) can I do that, that I only implement A's move constructor so it sets B's pointer to the new C, then every other member object will be moved/copied implicitly?

Comment: Or should I just use a unique_ptr?

Comment: If it needs a copy/move constructor for reallocating, why can I compile, while the contained element: Default copy constr./assign. is deleted, there is no move constr/assign. declared, and there can't be an implicitly declared move constr/assign, because I have a user-declared destructor. (Cppreference says that user declared destructor -> no implicit move constr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't there a better way than having pointers in A?

Yes, there is. Furthermore, I don't see how having pointers in `A` solves the problem.

A solution is to write a user defined copy constructor for `A`, that will update the pointer of the copied member.

> Or isn't there a simplier way than messing with copy constructor implementations?

No, a copy constructor is (perhaps arguably?) the simplest way to update the member pointer of the member.

> I thought that emplace constructs "in-place"

It does.

> so why does it need a copy ctr?

It doesn't in general.

It does require either a move or copy constructor in this case, because you pass it a temporary object. The object in the vector is constructed "in-place", by using the move (or copy, if not movable) constructor with the temporary as the argument.

Instead, you could have passed the arguments of the constructor of `A` direclty to `emplace_back` so that no temporary is involved.

Note that constructing the object in-place doesn't prevent the element of the vector from being copied, unless you have pre-reserved the memory so that no reallocation happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually write the copy constructor of `A` to do the right thing.

Another plan, if everything is standard layout, is to use offset pointers.  An offset pointer stores the difference in address between the pointer itself and what it points to.  It typically uses max(ptrdiff_t) for null.

If written carefully, these permit pointers between to sub structures to be default copyable, as the relative address of the two remains constant after a copy.

However, possibly a better plan is to augment all methods in `B` to take a pointer-to-C, and pass it in each time instead of storing redundant state.

A lot of what determines the right answer from the above has to do with the meaning of `A` `B` and `C`, and how independant they truly are.